# How to create a strong blur using the Image Convolution Function

Tags: php, image, filter, blur, convolution

I am trying to create a really blurred image using the PHP function image convolution.This image is used as a background behind the image in a slider.

I have tried using the Image Filter but the Gaussian Blur and Selective Blur are very light and you cant alter the blur's.

This is the code I am using at the moment to create the blur but its not really blurring the image enough.

```
    $matrix = array( array(5, 5, 5), array(0, 0, 0), array(5, 5, 5));
    for($i = 1; $i<=20; $i++) {
        imageconvolution($image, $matrix, 30, 0);
     }
```

I need a better for formula for the Matrix array's to create a stronger blur.

Comment: interesting! soon I will have to do digital processing image exam !